# matplotlib color map - predefine mappings to values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-2.x

I have an array that I am viewing using `imshow()`. (imsave() really, but the process should be identical).

I know that the values in the array will be between 0-9 and wonder if it is possible to use cmap to set each output to a specific 'color'.  Perhaps by mapping these to a dict?

Comment: Matplotlib docs seem to have a relevant example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html

Comment: This is honestly driving me crazy, I don't know why this is not possible directly. I've used low level libraries like D3.js etc, and this is really extremely basic but somehow Matplotlib does not support this without absurdly complicated normalization etc. steps in between... Well for the time being, we have to use 10 lines of code where one would suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a `ListedColormap`.

As a quick (but ugly) example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

cmap = ListedColormap(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'black'], 'indexed')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow([range(4)], interpolation='none', cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  As an addition, I notice that all HTML color names are supported: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp, so one does not need to wander around searching for names that work or manually code RBG / HEX codes.

Comment: But how do you do the mapping?? This doesnt work:     cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap({'green':1,
                                           'grey': -1,
                                           'red':0})

Comment: How does this answer the question? This is not a mapping as the OP requested, ListedColormap applies the first color to the first value encountered, giving you no control (as one would want by defining a custom mapping).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```py
def get_product_number_or_colormap(product=None, get_colormap=False):
    '''
    Get the number of the product or the colormap \\
    If get_colormap is True, return the colormap
    '''
    # Define product families and their corresponding numbers and colors
    product_families = {
        'Other': 'w',  # 'white
        'Semilla de Girasol': 'tab:pink',
        'MAIZ': 'tab:orange',
        'Trigo panificable': 'tab:green',
        'Cebada': 'tab:purple',
        'Urea': 'tab:grey',
        'Yara': 'tab:brown',
        'ACTH': 'tab:green',
        'AXAN': 'tab:red',
        'NAC27': 'tab:blue',
        'SULFAN': 'tab:cyan',
    }
    
    product_families_with_nums = {prod: {'number': num, 'color': product_families[prod]} for num, prod in enumerate(product_families)}
    # print(f"{product_families_with_nums=}")
    
    if get_colormap:
        # convert all colors to a list
        color_list = [product_families[prod] for prod in product_families]
        return colors.ListedColormap(color_list)
    
    # Else: Get the number and color for the product
    try:
        product_number = product_families_with_nums[product]['number']
    except KeyError:
        product_number = 1
        print(f"Product: {product} did not match any of the predefined products")
    
    return product_number
```

After you call this function:
Surface you want to paint:

```py
surface[:, surface_size] = get_product_number_or_colormap(product)
```

Use function you want: imshow/imsave/pcolormesh
(This code is extended so it also would work with pcolormesh)
You can get the cmap using:

```py
cmap = get_product_number_or_colormap(get_colormap=True)     
axs.flatten()[i].pcolormesh(x, y, surface, cmap=cmap, alpha=0.7, vmin=0, vmax=7)
```