# Matplotlib - Pick up one color associated to one value in a `colorbar`

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I would like to draw rectangles associated to some values `(X_i)`. Each of this rectangles will have a fill color depending to its value value `X_i`.

Is-it possible to use one `colorbar` and also to know which color is associated to one value ?

Comment: I think this answer does exactly what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207052/matplotlib-color-map-predefine-mappings-to-values with `ListedColormap`

Comment: Not really because this solution needs to define to gradient of the colors and I would like to simply use an existing color map.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.patches as patches

min_val = 0
max_val = 50

my_cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet') # or any other one
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(min_val, max_val) # the color maps work for [0, 1]

x_i = 15
color_i = my_cmap(norm(x_i)) # returns an rgba value

rect = patches.Rectangle((.5, .5), .25, .25, color=color_i) # make your rectangle

cmmapable = cm.ScalarMappable(norm, my_cmap)
cmmapable.set_array(range(min_val, max_val))

figure()
ax = gca()
ax.add_patch(rect)
colorbar(cmmapable)
show()
```

Will also get you a color bar on your graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm just starting to use matplotlib so sorry for my question.

Comment: @projetmbc See edit for how to get the a colorbar to show up as well.

Comment: and no worries about the question.  This is a reasonable question and involves digging a bit into the mpl internals.