# Matplotlib - Same padding as the one used by a `colorbar`

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

Is there a way to keep the same padding as the one used by a `colorbar` without seeing any `colobar` ?

Why ? Indeed, this will allow me to do one visual effect when passing from one plot without the color shading informations to the one using the colobar.

Here is one starting code coming from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235630/matplotlib-pick-up-one-color-associated-to-one-value-in-a-colorbar/15236334#comment21482421_15236334).

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
import matplotlib.cm as cm

min_val = 0
max_val = 1

# See : http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps
my_cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet') # or any other one
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(min_val, max_val) # the color maps work for [0, 1]

cmmapable = cm.ScalarMappable(norm, my_cmap)
cmmapable.set_array(range(min_val, max_val))

figure()
ax = gca()

cbar = colorbar(cmmapable, ticks=[0, 1])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['Min', 'Max'])

show()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "color shading informations", and I'm not really sure what you're trying to do? Right now you have a color bar on the figure with only 1 axes. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Yann I've updated my question. Hopping this is clearer... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to make a presentation or so with two slides, one with a plot without color bar and the next slide with the same plot with the color bar. The plots in the two slides should have the same sizes so that when you change the slides the plot does not jump or resize.

Setting the colormap will resize the original `Axes` instance. You can use `ax.get_position()` to get the bounding box of the resized `Axes`. It returns a bounding box: `Bbox(array([[ 0.125,  0.1  ], [ 0.745,  0.9  ]]))` It gives left, bottom, right and top edge. I find it easier to cheat a bit and use `ax._position.bounds`, which gives a rect (left edge, bottom edge, width, height) that you can directly use to make a new axes, as shown below.

```
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

min_val = 0
max_val = 1

my_cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('jet') 
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(min_val, max_val) 

cmmapable = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(norm, my_cmap)
cmmapable.set_array(range(min_val, max_val))

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)

cbar = plt.colorbar(cmmapable, ax = ax1, ticks=[0, 1])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['Min', 'Max'])

# gives bounding box with left, right, bottom, top
print(ax1.get_position())
# gives rectangle with left, bottom, width, height
print(ax1._position.bounds)

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_axes(ax1._position.bounds)

plt.show()
```

UPDATE: In the above solution there is no color bar, in the solution below there is a color bar, but you make it white and you remove the labels and the spines. If the background color of the figure is non-white, you'll see a white rectangle where the color bar is supposed to be.

```
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

min_val = 0
max_val = 1

my_cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('jet') 
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(min_val, max_val) 

cmmapable = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(norm, my_cmap)
cmmapable.set_array(range(min_val, max_val))

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)

# set opacity to 0
cbar = plt.colorbar(cmmapable, ax = ax1, ticks=[0, 1], alpha = 0)

# remove the tick labels
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['', ''])
# set the tick length to 0
cbar.ax.tick_params(axis = 'y', which = "both", length = 0)

# set everything that has a linewidth to 0
for a in cbar.ax.get_children():
    try:
        a.set_linewidth(0)
    except:
        pass

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot ! That does merely the job. I would also like to have a blank rectangle at the right of the graph which has the same width that the one used for displaying the colorbar. Why ? This will allow the graph without the colorbar and the one with to be at the same placed in my slider.

Comment: This is actually easier :) Just make a color bar and set the alpha (opacity) to zero:
`cbar = plt.colorbar(cmmapable, ax = ax1, ticks=[0, 1], alpha = 0)`
No need to use `ax1._position.bounds`.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that tha legend and the rectangle of the colorbar are still visible.