# Matplotlib - Title upon one `colobar`

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I need to add some text just upon one `colobar` to have a title for it. Is it possible ?

Here is one starting code coming from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235630/matplotlib-pick-up-one-color-associated-to-one-value-in-a-colorbar/15236334#comment21482421_15236334).

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
import matplotlib.cm as cm

min_val = 0
max_val = 1

# See : http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps
my_cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet') # or any other one
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(min_val, max_val) # the color maps work for [0, 1]

cmmapable = cm.ScalarMappable(norm, my_cmap)
cmmapable.set_array(range(min_val, max_val))

figure()
ax = gca()

cbar = colorbar(cmmapable, ticks=[0, 1])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['Min', 'Max'])

show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set_title` should do what you want [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_titlehttp://)

```
cbar.ax.set_title('title')
```

Comment: @projetmbc It is a big package, once you get your head around which bits and pieces fit together it is efficient documentation.  There is also an active effort to improve the documentation and make it more like the numpy docs. (MEP10)