# Python clustering 2d data to image?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a set of data in a 2d Array (72 * 144). The set of elements in that 2d array are from 1 - 12 and -999. Here is the snapshot of the 2d array

```
array([[   7,    7,    7, ...,    7,    7,    7],
       [   7,    7,    7, ...,    7,    7,    7],
       [-999, -999, -999, ..., -999, -999, -999],
       ...,
       [-999, -999, -999, ..., -999, -999, -999],
       [-999, -999, -999, ..., -999, -999, -999],
       [-999, -999, -999, ..., -999, -999, -999]], dtype=int32)
```

I want to create an image from this 2d array, which I have been able to create using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab as plt

A = np.fromfile('1984_Jan/yyyymmddhh.84010209', dtype='int32')
B = np.reshape(A, (72, 144))

plt.imshow(B, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap("Reds"), interpolation="nearest")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The image generated by this is only 2 colors, white and red (CMAP arg). I want it to generate 12 different colors, one for each element in data set. So, If a pixel is 1, then its some color and then when it's 2 then its another color and so on.

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply leave the arguments in `get_cmap` blank in order to have different color for different numbers:

`plt.imshow(B, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap(), interpolation="nearest")`

But this is approach will not create a decent image at least in my opinion. Thus I suggest you to use some designated color bar map, but not using those sequential colormaps, for example using a `gist_rainbow` map will make it better:

`plt.imshow(a, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap("gist_rainbow"), interpolation="nearest")`

Finally, check out [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) you could find all the color maps matplotlib supplies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still only see two colors, I want to assign a color to each pixel.

Comment: @Pete The reason why you see only two colors should be due to you have -999, such am extreme number, in your matrix and which will make the color maps chaotic. The easiest way to solve it could be assign all the -999 to 0 by `a[np.where(a==-999)]=0`. Then I will be sure that you see multiple colors.

Comment: @Pete Also if you tend to build your own palette, check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207052/matplotlib-color-map-predefine-mappings-to-values) and [here](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn-dev/tutorial/color_palettes.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help 0x382fd442.