# Custom colormap by mapping dictionary values (not directly indexed).

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I have a 2d numpy array that shows anatomical data for the brain.Elements of the array that belong to different anatomical regions have a different value. So for example the caudoputamen has a value of 672, and the thalamus has a value of 3987.

I also have a dictionary that maps these integers into colours. I am trying to plot a slice of the array(2d image), and create a colormap that uses the color specified by the dictionary for this specific id, but I have failed in creating this colormap so far. Does anyone have an idea on how to approach this problem?

So for example,

data_array is a 2d numpy array containing integers. For simplicity, lets suppose it only contains the numbers for different regions: 44, 83, 5611, 22.

I also have a dictionary in this form: color_dict = {44:'blue', 83:'green', 5611:'red', 22:'yellow'}

What i want to do is:

plt.imshow(data_array[:,:], cmap=color_dict)

The end result I expect when i see the image is, the elements of the array that have a value of 44 to be blue, the ones that have a value of 83 to be green and so on. I tried creating a ListedColormap but it does some weird normalizations.the problem with that is that the integer entries might be different in scale. So, I do not want any kind of normalization, just a mapping of integer values into colors.

Before this gets marked as a duplicate of [matplotlib color map - predefine mappings to values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207052/matplotlib-color-map-predefine-mappings-to-values) please not that in that case the colormap is directly indexed into values[0-9].

Comment: So the idea is of course to first map your numbers to the integers 0,1,2,3,etc. and then apply the solution from the linked question.

Comment: Ok I thought about it, but was wondering if there is a another way. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: can you submit your comment as the answer so i can upvote?

Comment: In a way you don't need to do the mapping yourself if you use a `BoundaryNorm`. Check out the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47778106/4124317). And also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52932972/4124317). I feel like I would need to repeat myself when answering here, so we can mark as duplicate of those; unless of course there is some trouble with implementing those - in which case you could update your question with the actual code (a [mcve]) and the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks so much that's what I was looking for.

Comment: The first answer you posted got me what i wanted to do, so we can mark as duplicate. Thanks again.